# Which open source software is good for community elections?

Tags: open-source, voting

I am part of a community organisation which holds annual leadership elections. We are a fully open organisation but currently use a closed source platform to run these elections which clearly does not feel right.

Ideally, the system should have an API which allows us to automatically create elections. It should also have cloud or self host options.

Do you have any recommendations as to which software we could use instead?

Comment: For any serious election, it's best not to use any software at all.

Comment: I get that, but we are only a small community group. I doubt anyone will want to interfere with our elections.

Comment: I suggest doing a search on github.com. In the past on drupal 7, I used its "election" and "election_fptp" modules. But not sure they have been upgraded.